# Three types of Neutral technological Change

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, solow, technological-progress

Can you tell me why the isoquants changes as per pic below in the three cases of neutral technological change: i) Hicks neutral, ii) Solow neutral, iii) Harrod neutral

[image]